# Caribbean ghost story anthology c. 1980s/90s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ghost

Not James Berry's work but a collection by a woman whose name I have unfortunately forgotten.  All stories based on traditional folk tales.  The two story titles I think I remember are 'Rose Hall' and 'The Intake'.

The latter tale was about a police constable distracted from his duties by a beautiful young lady, who coaxes him away from his patrol route towards a quiet reservoir known as an 'intake'.  But she is really a djablesse (she-devil).  She is just about to seize him when some (car?) lights shining from the other side of the intake accidentally highlight the gold buttons on his uniform.  These form the shape of a cross.  The cheated djablesse immediately vanishes, shrieking 'You lucky!  You luckee-ee!!' at her traumatised prey.

Another good story features a young man meeting the wrong person at a crossroads at Hallowe'en.  There are also tales of duppies, soucriants and Papa Bois.

Comment: Ten seconds of search reveals a couple of Caribbean ghost collections that might be right; http://weirdtalesmagazine.com/2013/09/21/the-weird-bookshelf-voodoo-tales-the-ghost-stories-of-henry-s-whitehead/ and http://www.amazon.co.uk/Penguin-Book-Caribbean-Short-Stories/dp/0140245030

Comment: Thanks for looking, they are interesting in themselves but not the one I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching "Intake" on [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org) led to this author--[Grace Hallworth](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?122812). The collection is called *Mouth Open, Story Jump Out* and includes stories called "The Intake", "Papa Bois", and "The Soucouyant". It was published in 1984.

Comment: This is it!  Thank you! Naturally I was convinced I remembered the author's name, and it was Patricia Something.  Thank you very much, I shall hunt a copy down.